# Computing logarithmic derivatives of modified Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: r, function, derivative, bessel-functions

I want to know how I can compute the first and second derivatives of logarithm of modified Bessel function of the second kind.

For instance, I'm interested in finding the following derivatives with respect to x:

- ∂/∂x log(K_(x))
- ∂^2/∂x^2 log(K_(x))

The first derivative is equivalent to (∂/∂x(K_(x))) / K_(x). I could use both R functions 'BesselK' (can be found in [Bessel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Bessel.html) and [fOptions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fOptions/versions/251.70/topics/BesselFunctions) packages) and 'BesselDK' ([fOptions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fOptions/versions/251.70/topics/BesselFunctions) package) to calculate this. Is there a better alternative?

Particularly, how to calculate the second derivative above in R? I couldn't find anything specific anywhere.

Comment: You should be able to find clues there https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/20/02/02/

Comment: You haven't offered a source for those functions. They are surely not part of base R.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing "is there a function to ... ?" to "how do I ... ?", which is more on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking out Python's `sympy` library (because R doesn't have native symbolic computation facilities):

```py
from sympy import *
nu, x = symbols('nu, x')
b = log(besselk(nu, x))
b1 = b.diff(x)
print(b1)
b2 = b1.diff(x)
print(b2)
```

Translating the results into R code (for convenience I'm defining a `besselk` that swaps the order of the arguments to match Python)

```
besselk <- function(nu, x) besselK(x, nu)
blogd <- function(x, nu) {
   (-besselk(nu - 1, x)/2 - besselk(nu + 1, x)/2)/besselk(nu, x)
}
blogd2 <- function(x, nu) {
   (-besselk(nu - 1, x)/2 - besselk(nu + 1, x)/2)*(besselk(nu - 1, x)/2 + 
     besselk(nu + 1, x)/2)/besselk(nu, x)**2 + (besselk(nu, x)/2 + 
     besselk(nu - 2, x)/4 + besselk(nu + 2, x)/4)/besselk(nu, x)
}
```

Check results:

```
blogd(1.5, 2.5)
## [1] -2.051282
blogd2(1.5, 2.5)
## [1] 0.9375411
```

```
library(numDeriv)
lb <- function(x, nu) log(besselK(x, nu))
grad(lb, x = 1.5, nu = 2.5)
## [1] -2.051282
drop(hessian(lb, x = 1.5, nu = 2.5))
##  0.9375411
```

I was lazy and cut-and-pasted the output from `sympy`. These functions would be made more efficient by vectorizing the calls to `besselK` (e.g. `bvec <- besselK(x, nu = nu + (-2:2))`) and plugging the values in to the formula (as it is, `besselK` is called more times than necessary, especially in the second-derivative calculation; vectorization might not matter much, but not calling `besselK` more times than necessary would make a big difference).

PS `BesselK`, `BesselDK` are in the [now-removed-from-CRAN fAsianOptions package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fAsianOptions/index.html)